# Function executing prior to .then() promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

**GOAL:** Create arrays in JSON if html elements outnumber existing JSON file's arrays. Then, obtain the `.length` of each array and add to `btn` that will be appended to html.

I have a script that starts off detecting how many `postWrapper` elements are on my page, it then loops through them and determines if `comments`, `likes` and `views` (three variables that store three external JSON files) all have a corresponding arrays for each indexed `postWrapper` element. If the array does not exist within one of the JSON files, the `postArray()` function makes an `$.ajax` call and php writes an empty array to the end of each JSON file. You'll then see I use `.push([])` to add an empty array to the existing `comments`, `likes` and `views` variables as well, so that they too reflect the updated JSON files.

I'm using `.then()` to ensure some of these functions are performed synchronously. *After* the JSON files have been updated and empty arrays have been pushed to existing js variables I then need to append buttons to the `postWrapper` elements with the help of my `injectBtn()` function. This function reads the `comments`, `likes` and `views` variables to determine the `.length` of the arrays, then adds a count, if you will.

The problem I am facing is that if one of these three JSON files doesn't have a sufficient number of arrays, the `postArray()` function seems to successfully execute (so the JSON files are updated), but the js variables that get the `.push([])` method don't update before `injectBtn()` attempts to execute and obtain the `.length` of newly created arrays. I am then left with the following error(s):

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

How can I resolve this so that both my JSON files and `comments`, `likes` and `views` variables are updated before `injectBtn()` tries to read the `.length` of arrays contained within them?

My code is below (at least the parts I think are relevant). Please let me know if you have any questions or need any more context.

```
    var postArray = function() {

        return $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/php/api.php",
            dataType: "text",
            data: {
                array: "new"
            }
        });

    }

    var injectBtns = function(element, index) {
        $(element[index]).append(
            "<a class='js comment btn' href='#' title='Comment'>" +
                "<span class='js comment count'>" + comments[index].length + "</span>" +
                "<svg class='icon' width='16px' height='16px' viewbox='0 0 16 16'>" +
                    "<use xlink:href='/assets/icons.svg#comments'></use>" +
                "</svg>" +
            "</a>" +
            "<a class='js like btn' href='#' title='Like'>" +
                "<span class='js like count'>" + likes[index].length + "</span>" +
                "<svg class='icon' width='16px' height='16px' viewbox='0 0 16 16'>" +
                    "<use xlink:href='/assets/icons.svg#likes'></use>" +
                "</svg>" +
            "</a>" +
            "<a class='js view btn' href='#' title='Like'>" +
                "<span class='js view count'>" + views[index].length + "</span>" +
                "<svg class='icon' width='16px' height='16px' viewbox='0 0 16 16'>" +
                    "<use xlink:href='/assets/icons.svg#views'></use>" +
                "</svg>" +
            "</a>"
        );
    }

    var postWrapper = $(".js.post.wrapper"),
        commentBtn = ".js.comment.btn",
        likeBtn = ".js.like.btn",
        viewBtn = ".js.view.btn";

    for (var i = 0; i < $(postWrapper).length; i++) {

        (function(index) {

            if (typeof comments[index] === "undefined" || typeof likes[index] === "undefined" || typeof views[index] === "undefined") {

                postArray().then(function() {
                    comments.push([]);
                    likes.push([]);
                    views.push([]);

                    injectBtns(postWrapper, index);
                });
            } else {
                injectBtns(postWrapper, index);
            }

        })(i);

        if (comments[i].includes(client)) {
            $(postWrapper[i]).children(commentBtn).addClass("active");
        }

        if (likes[i].includes(client)) {
            $(postWrapper[i]).children(likeBtn).addClass("active");
            $(postWrapper[i]).children(likeBtn).prop("title", "Unlike");
        }

        if (views[i].includes(client)) {
            $(postWrapper[i]).children(viewBtn).addClass("active");
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should take a look at [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) you can use that to determine when all the AJAX calls are done.

Comment: "*I'm using `.then()` to ensure some of these functions are performed synchronously.*" - no, that's not how promises work. `then` ensures that *the callback* is executed sequentially, but it still happens asynchronously after the promise is fulfilled, and everything else runs normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I resolve this so that both my JSON files and comments, likes and views variables are updated before injectBtn() tries to read the .length of arrays contained within them?

You will need to put them inside the `then` callback as well.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $(postWrapper).length; i++) {
    (function(i) {

        var promise = (typeof comments[i] === "undefined" || typeof likes[i] === "undefined" || typeof views[i] === "undefined")
          ? postArray().then(function() {
                comments.push([]);
                likes.push([]);
                views.push([]);
            })
          : $.when(undefined);

        promise.then(function() {
            injectBtns(postWrapper, i);

            if (comments[i].includes(client)) {
                $(postWrapper[i]).children(commentBtn).addClass("active");
            }

            if (likes[i].includes(client)) {
                $(postWrapper[i]).children(likeBtn).addClass("active");
                $(postWrapper[i]).children(likeBtn).prop("title", "Unlike");
            }

            if (views[i].includes(client)) {
                $(postWrapper[i]).children(viewBtn).addClass("active");
            }
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Notice that this whole approach is pretty horrible

- To guard against race conditions, you should not just request to "make a new array (at the end)" but rather "make an array at position `i` (if it doesn't already exist)".
- Instead of making multiple requests (one for every single missing array), you should make one simple request that has the number of expected arrays (i.e `postWrapper.length`). The php script should then generate as many as necessary.
- You should not use clientside scripting for this at all, or even accept requests to make individual comment/like/view sections (which is a huge security risk). The php server should know how many posts are on which page, and serve the json with the correct number of arrays in the first place.

Comment: I'm going to try and debug the answer you've provided above. It seems to be to do with the ternary operator or `promise` variable declaration. Thank you for all your insights.

Comment: @danMad Debug? Is something not working? Oh, I left a stray brace in there.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not too familiar with the ternary operator so wasn't entirely sure what was wrong as I haven't seen a ternary conditional formatted over multiple lines in the way that you wrote it. To give more context, I'm a designer who's taught myself to code, and so my questionable/terrible way of constructing a likes/views/comments system with JSON is a way to convey my design/ux/front-end chops with a super light-weight system that doesn't involve me having to learn all about databases/server-side as time is of the essence. Really appreciate your help and insights. Thank you.

Comment: Well, if you're just learning to program it's probably fine, or when making a quick demonstration prototype or some toy for playing around in a restricted environment. But for anything you are developing for a client, or that goes live in production on the web (even if its just your personal blog), you will need to learn the backend (or work with an architect who knows this stuff). Security must happen on the server side.